# Does Ext JS support internationalization

Tags: extjs

Does Ext JS support internationalization

Answer (score 4):

It has both [static](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/locale/dutch-form.html) and [dynamic](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/locale/multi-lang.html) localisation.

Comment: That's a bit misleading: ExtJS internationalization relies on overrides (in other words: monkey-patching) and only affects DOM content render after the fact. There's no real built-in support for proper internationalization. It's all a bit bolted on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, internationalization is supported with Ext JS:

https://www.sencha.com/blog/internationalization-localization-with-sencha-ext-js/

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS only helps localize the string resources it uses. Although with a [**bug**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132919-Ext-JS-4.0-Locale-not-loading-as-it-should...&p=601150) currently.
It doesn't provide any utility to localize custom string resources. However, you could follow the way proposed by ExtJS or select any other [**alternative**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?117931-extjs-localization-in-multiple-languages) available.